# How to execute a function that returns an Oracle UDT (User data type) in WSO2 DSS?

Tags: oracle, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-data-services-server

I've tried with:

```
select package.faunction(param1,param2...paramX) as "data" from dual.
```

Works like a charm. Then, I´ve got the output result with:

```
element column="data[0]" name="name1" xsdType="string"
element column="data[1]" name="name2" xsdType="string"
```

And that works too. But when the output has more than 10 columns I've got an exception

> Cannot find parameter with type:column name:data[10] DS Code: INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR

Any idea what I can do to make this work with more than 10 parameters?

PS: If I use the same query with the "User column numbers" option checked and `<element column="1" name="result" xsdType="string"/>` as output mapping WORKS, but all the UDT came in just one column.